# Remove unwanted email address associated with Apple ID

Tags: icloud, apple-id

I noticed that I have an unwanted email address in the following panel:

System Preferences → iCloud → Account Details → Contact

What does that mean and how can I remove it?

[image]

Update:

I have tried to log on Apple ID settings but it doesn't work:

There is NO `x` besides that email but a `?` saying:

> This is an alias of your Apple ID email address.

[image]

Updated 2:
It seems there is no way to remove it:
[image: It seems there is no way to remove it]

Comment: Log into [Apple ID website](https://appleid.apple.com/) and click on Edit button under Security section. You should be able to locate the email address in question listed there. Check if you see a circular button with a cross ahead of the email address, click on it to disassociate it from your account. See if that helps.

Comment: not working. Updated my question.

Comment: The @icloud.com email address is created by Apple when registering an Apple ID. As far as I understand, it cannot be deleted. That's why you don't get a cross against it.

Comment: @NimeshNeema They can be, but they can also be created later, in which case it really _ought_ to be reversible. <_< https://support.apple.com/guide/icloud/create-an-icloudcom-email-address-mmdd8d1c5c/icloud

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally solved it.

I have made a call to their customer support and told them this is very important for me (personally).

The staff told me she would ask her supervisor to review my case and had very little chance to achieve it.

After a few days, they helped me removed it.

Answer (score 3):

#### Method #1: Normal Email Address

If you [log into your Apple ID](https://appleid.apple.com/) you can access your associated emails by clicking on the "Edit" button next to your account info.

*screenshot of account info*

[image: ss1]

From there you'll see all the email addresses associated with your Apple ID. You can delete them or add new ones here.

*screenshot of account details - email address*

[image: ss2]

*Delete additional emails by clicking on the 'X' next to it*

[image: ss3]

**NOTE:** Any new email addresses will require that you MFA ([Multi-factor authenticate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-factor_authentication)) then through your associated phone number that you setup with your Apple ID.

#### Method #2: An alias email address (XXX@icloud.com)

If you have an alias email address of the form `XXXXX@icloud.com` that's a different matter. This is an alias that Apple can add to your account. To remove these you can follow the directions in this Apple discussion titled: [How do I delete an alias from my Apple ID](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8435649).

Steps:

> Change, turn off, turn on, or delete an alias
>
> 1. Click the Action pop-up menu [image: ssmenubutton] in the sidebar, then choose Preferences.
> 2. Click Accounts.
> 3. Select the alias in the Addresses list, then do any of the following:
>
>    - Turn off an alias: Select “Disable alias.”
>    - Delete an alias: Click Delete.
> 4. Click Done.

**NOTE:** The Action pop-up menu is under the Mail application after you open it in icloud (www.icloud.com).

#### Method #3: Revised directions from Apple

I found these steps outlined in the official documentation from apple in this KB titled: [iCloud: Use email aliases in iCloud Mail](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH2622?locale=en_US).

These steps were recently updated (April 9th, 2019) as follows:

> #### Change, turn off, turn on, or delete an alias
>
> 1. Click the Action pop-up menu [image: ss] in the sidebar, then choose Preferences.
> 2. Click Accounts.
> 3. Select the alias in the Addresses list, then do any of the following:
>
>    - Change the name or label: Enter a new alias name and label in the fields provided. Alias names must contain between 3 and 20 characters.
>    - Choose a new color for incoming messages: Click a Label Color option.
>    - Alias labels appear only in Mail on iCloud.com.
>    - Turn off an alias: Select “Disable alias.”
>    - Turn on an alias: Deselect “Disable alias.”
>    - Delete an alias: Click Delete.
> 4. Click Done.

Comment: @AGamePlayer - did this resolve your issue?

Comment: I have updated the question. Still no way :(

Comment: @AGamePlayer - take a look at Method #3, these are recently updated steps directly from Apple's official docs.

Comment: I do not have the 'Disable Alias' option anywhere

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. There is no way. I’ve tried. I chatted for hours online and escalated it as high up as possible, but they will not remove it - no matter what. Their solution is for you to start over and use your old login for purchases and iTunes. There is absolutely nothing they will do under any circumstances. Nothing!

Answer (score 0):

To delete an something@icloud.com address from your account that says "This is an alias of your Apple ID email address"

- on https://appleid.apple.com
- change your Apple ID to the @icloud.com email
- refresh the page and verify that it now has the correct id
- (I then removed all other emails addresses but this may not be necessary)
- now change your Apple ID to the email address you want
- after the account has updated you can delete the @icloud.com (it now has an `X` instead of the `?`)

This procedure worked at the end of 2021.

Comment: I tried changing my email to icloud.com and back to me.com thinking the icloud.com address would then be marked as deletable alias. But after changing my AppleID to icloud.com my me.com address is blocked now and I can't change it back. After some research it seems like a 30 days lockout. Hopefully I can really change it back after a month and didn't block my me.com address for a whole year or forever. But this answer isn't really a fast solution, to me it seems it doesn't work at all. I changed my AppleID now to something completely different and still can't delete the icloud.com alias.

Comment: It worked for me when I used it to change to an unrelated email address. I wouldn't do it with @me.com as this is a domain for discontinued services that belongs to apple and is probably treated as a special case by the system.