# Removing an unwanted iCloud.com alias address "This is an alias of your Apple ID email address" error

Tags: icloud, email, apple-id, gmail, alias

I've been using my Apple ID since 2017 with "real@gmail.com". In an experiment to use iCloud custom domains I created "test@icloud.com" which is now tied to the account as Alias. I assumed I could just remove the iCloud when I was finished because it's just an alias and not the primary email I used to sign up for the AppleID.

Unfortunately I get the error ""This is an alias of your Apple ID email address"" with no option of removal.

[image]

Now this is super disappointing however upon looking up online, somebody says they had success by changing their AppleID to the iCloud (in my case test@icloud.com). Then they changed the AppleID to the email address they wanted (real@gmail.com) and the ability to delete the iCloud account populated. Since this test@icloud.com account is newer than 30 days for me, I can't test this out, but was wondering if others had experience with this method of getting an alias dissociated with your account? I just want my AppleID to be real@gmail.com and nothing else.

[Link to comment explaining the option to remove the alias came up after doing the above](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/434371/469003)